# Cannot add event listener to nested SVG element

Tags: javascript, svg, addeventlistener

I'm having trouble adding and firing an event listener with javascript on this svg element. Js is at the bottom of the code block.  I can set the target ID to a variable no problem.  It's attaching an event listener and doing "something" on click/hover that seems to be the issue.  The end goal is to show the box when hovering over the dot by adjusting the opacity.

```js
var dot15 = document.getElementById('Dot_15');
var box15 = document.getElementById('Info_Box_15');

dot15.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  box15.style.opacity = "1";
});
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="777.6px" height="491px" viewBox="607.3 235.5 777.6 491" style="enable-background:new 607.3 235.5 777.6 491;" xml:space="preserve">

     <style type="text/css">
      .st0{fill:#00A76F;}
      .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
      .st2{font-family:'BarlowCondensed-SemiBold';}
      .st3{font-size:14px;}
      .st4{font-family:'BarlowCondensed-Medium';}
      .st5{font-size:12px;}
      .st6{opacity:0.15;fill:#454544;}
      #Info_Box_15 {opacity:0}
     </style>

     <g id="Info_Box_15">
      <polygon class="st0" points="1156.7,556.4 1149,548.4 1073,548.4 1073,501.4 1156.7,501.4   "/>
      <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1076.6688 516.0011)"><tspan x="0" y="0" class="st1 st2 st3">Gasden</tspan><tspan x="0" y="14" class="st1 st4 st5">Gasden, Alabama</tspan><tspan x="0" y="28" class="st1 st4 st5">89,000 sq. ft.</tspan> 
         </text>
     </g>
     <g id="Dot_15" transform="translate(608.399428608477,176.3959312419786)" cursor="pointer">
      <path class="st0" d="M548.3,389.1L548.3,389.1c1.9,0,3.5-1.5,3.5-3.5v0c0-1.9-1.5-3.5-3.5-3.5h0c-1.9,0-3.5,1.5-3.5,3.5v0
  C544.9,387.5,546.4,389.1,548.3,389.1z"/>
     </g>

     <g id="Site_x5F_3_x5F_Blue_x5F_Valley">
      <g id="Info_box_3">
       <polygon class="st0" points="1018.2,467.3 1010.5,459.4 934.5,459.4 934.5,412.3 1018.2,412.3   "/>
       <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 938.1677 426.9739)"><tspan x="0" y="0" class="st1 st2 st3">BLUE VALLEY</tspan><tspan x="0" y="14" class="st1 st4 st5">Kansas City, KS</tspan><tspan x="0" y="28" class="st1 st4 st5">83,224 sq. ft.</tspan></text>
      </g>
      <g id="Dot_3" transform="translate(608.399428608477,176.3959312419786)">
       <path class="st0" d="M409.8,300L409.8,300c1.9,0,3.5-1.5,3.5-3.5v0c0-1.9-1.5-3.5-3.5-3.5h0c-1.9,0-3.5,1.5-3.5,3.5v0
   C406.4,298.5,407.9,300,409.8,300z"/>
      </g>
     </g>
```

Comment: I'm not very sure I understand you. Do you think that adding an other event listener on mouse leave and making the opacity 0 would solve your problem?

Comment: Your code works, though you're missing a closing svg tag. All I see missing is setting it back to `opacity:0` on `mouseout` so not sure what your asking.

Comment: I didn't post the entire svg because it's over 2000 lines. @enxaneta no.  I have opacity set to 0 on the box initial state.  When a user hovers over the dot (#Dot_15) I need to set the opacity to "1" on the box (#Info_Box_15).  I can't get the dom to recognize the hover/mouseover state.

Comment: What's odd is this snippet on this page does run as intended, however when I test locally it does not.

Comment: Are you including the SVG inline in your HTML?  Or are you loading it as an `<img>` or something?